# spdlog question : is there a way not output timestamp?

Tags: c++, logging, timestamp, spdlog

my use case is to just use spdlog as my serialization library. For example. I would like to output json data, but the timestamp goes together with the json make it an invalid json syntax. Of course I could remove the time stamp programmatically later, but I am wondering whether if SPDLOG offers a way to skip the timestamp.

Comment: Maybe use their [custom formatting](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/3.-Custom-formatting)?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the Timing and Logger name from output, add the following at the start of your code:

```
spdlog::set_pattern("%v");
```

For more details check out : [custom formatting](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/3.-Custom-formatting)